# AABB vs Sphere Collision on edges

Tags: javascript, physics

I implemented a simple AABB vs Sphere collision using this method [from gamedev](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/335465-is-this-the-simplest-sphere-aabb-collision-test/#entry3181375).
It works fine when the sphere collides with the box from all sides.

The problem is that the sphere will not slip of the edge of the box. Meaning when the sphere falling in -y direction collides on the edge of the box, it will just go in +y direction again. See the picture below (taken after collision).

I think the problem is that the contactnormal is in this case always [0, 1, 0]. How do I achieve a more realistic behavior?
For vector calculations I am using [glMatrix](http://glmatrix.net/).

```
var delta = vec3.create();
vec3.subtract(delta, centerRelSphereAABB, closestPoint);
distance = vec3.length(delta);

if(distance < C.radius){

    penetrationDepth = C.radius - distance;

    contactNormal = vec3.create();
    vec3.subtract(contactNormal, delta, A.centerOfMass);
    vec3.normalize(contactNormal, delta);

    //contact point
    contactPoint = vec3.create();
    vec3.scale(contactPoint, contactNormal, C.radius - penetrationDepth);
    vec3.subtract(contactPoint, model_1.centerOfMass, contactPoint);
}
```

The data is then forwarded to my collision response.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ditch your contact normal.  The vector Delta that you have at the start IS the collision normal when the object is a sphere.  You'll have to normalize it, and probably negate it, but it's in the right direction.

Not true in a general case of other shapes ...